# Tracking Active Subscriptions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm currently in the process of developing a sheet that can track customers and their current subscription status to our program. Someome can either purchase a week or a month depending on their needs. A week adds 7 days, whereas a month adds 31 days.

The issue im currently trying to work around is that of not being able to recognise if someone re-subs prior to their sub ending. I'm attempting to do this through formulas.

For example;
Someone subs for a month today. It displays how many days left they currently have/the date of expiry. Two weeks later (while still subscribed) they decide to re-sub for another week or month in advance of their sub ending. I need this to be added on to their current subcription. The issue arrises where I can't go off the date they resubbed because they already have a sub and it wouldnt recognise how many days they currently have.

The system im trying to develop is as follows;

- Whenever someone subscribes, you go into the logging sheet put in the date they subbed and if its a week or a month.
- The sheets adds the relevant time period on to their subscription if ongoing, or begins their sub from the day of purchase.
- There will be a database sheet that shows everyones name, subscription status, and when it ends (if currently subbed)

To simplify ive made a text format replica of how the sheet should perform. These will be prefixed by [1].

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bD7X3NOx_q5jjaqq-lVleNcNyvkvSEexzCp42R5KyDs/edit#gid=1087508278

I really appreciate anyone taking the time to help me out on this one, its been quite a challange to try and find a solution thus far.

Thank you in advance,
Harry

I've searched through forms and tried so many different formulas but i just simply can't develop a system that can do this. Either it won't count the fact they are already subscribed or if someones sub expires then a couple of months/weeks later they resub, it wont go off the new date.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Simplify your question. This is too much detail. [Please review how to ask a quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)